# Android textview anchor center instead of top left

Tags: android, android-layout

I am not finding anyway to change the anchorpoint/origin of my textview to the center. I am trying to increase the font size but I want it to grow from the center of the textview instead of the top left point.

Edit: Update with image

Blue: Origin

Purple: Center

If origin is top left like 1 & 2 the center moves off of 0,0 when the view gets bigger.

I am wanting to get it so the center point never moves like in 3 & 4. If 3 grew to 4 it would still have the same center.

[image]

Comment: Is this what you are talking about `android:gravity="center"`?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want....

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textSize="30dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll paste an example that a really hope could help:

// to creat text Paint

```
Paint text = new Paint();
```

// to define text properties:

```
text.setColor(Color.GRAY);
text.setStyle(Style.FILL);
text.setFakeBoldText(true);
text.setAntiAlias(true);
text.setTextSize((float) (30));
text.setAlpha(95);
```

// my "canvas" (actually, kind of a subcanvas) has 120 in width

// to center at Y axis

```
int yPos = (int) (yTarget - ((text.descent() + text.ascent()) / 2));
```

// to center at X axis

```
int xPos = (int) (120/2 - text.measureText("+.25°")/2);
```

// to write the text at right position:

```
canvas.drawText("+.25°", xPos, yPos, text);
```